# Android Studio cannot initiate the constraint layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

[enter image description here]

At the top right, next to the zoom buttons a blue warning appears which basically says :

Failed to initiate one or more classes

The following classes could not be instantiated:

- android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

with exception details:

Exception Details java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/constraint/R$styleable android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:599) android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.(ConstraintLayout.java:576) java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)

And also in the text format of activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

On the tools:context=".MainActivity" line .MainActivity appears in red color saying "Unresolved class MainActivity"

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kaan.asd">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm new to Android Studio and I've been trying to solve the problem for quite some time now, I have tried clearing caches, clean/rebuild project but neither solved my issue.
I am using the Android Studio 3.3.1 version with gradle version of 4.10.1 on Windows.
I'd appriciate it if anyone could help me fix it.

Comment: are you using new mdc or support library?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the repository of constraint layout in the android directory: **app/build.gradle** like below:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

Then sync your project and enjoy this perfect layout.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I added the line you have given, in app/build.gradle under dependencies tag, but I still have the same issue with same errors.

Comment: I don’t know if I should’ve added it under another tag though

Comment: @KaanAlgan can got to File -> invalidate/cache -->Invalidate and restart

Comment: @Aadit33 I fixed it by reinstalling the Android Studio, and it worked.